# Can I print each value in a for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm still a beginner in Python and after numerous Google searches and Stack Overflow searches I still can't find what I assume is a simple answer for my problem. I was trying to make a simple Python program that would take 10 values for student's names and 10 values to take in the amount of absences each student had before printing them out into a matrix. This ended up working fine, however I could only do it by using something like:

```
student0 = raw_input("Enter Student 1's name: ")
student0Abs = raw_input("Enter Student 1's absences: ")
```

when I want to do something like:

```
for s in range(1,11):
    students = str(raw_input("Enter student name " + str(s-1) + ": "))
```

So I don't have to write essentially the same line 10 times over every time I want to do something (I can't figure out how to use the above line to print all indiviual inputs and put them in a matrix). Is this possible and if so can someone please help me with a link or the solution itself? Thanks very much in advance if so!

Comment: I don't see any reason to vote down this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily put it in a loop, it's not a problem:

```
students = []
student_abs = []
for i in range(10):
    students.append(raw_input("Enter Student %d's name: " % i+1))
    student_abs.append(raw_input("Enter Student %d's absences: " % i+1))
```

In your example, you're overwriting the value of `students` each time. Just put it in a list, and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of dictionaries:

```
students = []
for num in range(1, 11):
  students.append({
    "name": raw_input("Enter Student %i's name: " % num),
    "absences": raw_input("Enter Student %i's absences: " % num)
  })
```

Comment: That would result in a dictionary, just saying.